# How can I rewrite this JavaScript to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Following are some individual JavaScript statements from a block of java-script code. I want to convert this JavaScript code in PHP so that I can execute it server-side. In the following snippet, there are some operators used, such as `>>`, `>>>`, `~`, `^`, `<<`, `<<<`, etc.

How can I translate these JavaScript functions to PHP?

```
function core_enc(K, F) {
    K[F >> 5] |= 128 << ((F) %32);
    K[(((F + 64) >>> 9) << 4) + 14] = F;
}

function enc_ff(C, B, G, F, A, E, D) {
    return enc_cmn((B & G) | ((~B) & F), C, B, A, E, D);
}

function enc_hh(C, B, G, F, A, E, D) {
    return enc_cmn(B ^ G ^ F, C, B, A, E, D);
}

function safe_add(A, D) {
    var C = (A & 65535) + (D & 65535);
    var B = (A >> 16) + (D >> 16) + (C >> 16);
    return (B << 16) | (C & 65535);
}

function bit_rol(A, B) {
    return (A << B) | (A >>> (32 - B));
}
```

Comment: this isn't code for the MD5 hash is it?

Answer (score 2):

That would be the *exact same operators*. See http://codepad.org/b5uZPCu4 for a demo.

The shift operators `>>` and `<<` can be directly translated, as well as other basic bitwise operations such as `|` (or), `&` (and), `^` (xor), `~` (not), etcetera. PHP arrays also work in the same fashion, and the functions have about the same syntax. Your JavaScript code should work perfectly in PHP with minimal changes (e.g. `variableName` becomes `$variableName`, you remove `var`, and `>>>` doesn't work in PHP.)

Edit: If this is actually code for MD5 or something, PHP provides the convenient function [`md5`](http://php.net/function.md5) to do that for you.